# Remove duplicates from DataFrame view

Tags: python, pandas

I have code similar to this:

```
df = raw_report[some_columns].copy()
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

I used `copy()` to avoid a warning about uncertainty wrt view / copy.  However, I'd like to use a view, because later I only read from this `DataFrame`.  The line that generated the warning was the line that removes duplicates, so I assume it doesn't generate a view.

Thus, my question: is there a way to remove duplicates from the view?  Or, rather, is there a way to refine a view such that it doesn't contain duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need parameter subset for drop duplicates by only some columns in [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
raw_report.drop_duplicates(subset=[some_columns],inplace=True)
```

Comment: Well... not exactly. After I do this, `df._is_view` is `False`. So, I'm guessing that `drop_duplicates` won't create a view in general. But maybe there's some other way? `groupby()` does something kind of similar.

Comment: Hmmm, my solution remove duplicates in original df, no in view. So instead 2 step solution I create one step. But if need original with dupes and then another df(as view), then no sure if exist some solution without copy and without hard set `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` what is bad idea.